# How to disable class in a particular table column?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

i am not sure if this is possible or not. 
Anyway i want to disable .sorting class from one column, the class is of bootstrap. Please check the URL image for more.

http://prntscr.com/ftebsr

Thank you.

Comment: What you have tried so far? Also provide the code for better understanding

Comment: try pointer-events:none; for that coloumn

Comment: which table plugin you are using?

Comment: Hi ! It would be better if you checkout [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code for future endeavor at Stack overflow. -Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think your code is like this

```
<th><b>#</b> <i class="fa fa-fw fa-sort"></i></th>
```

then you can use css to disable for any column like this(eg:-first column)

```
th:nth-child(1) .fa-sort{
  display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your screenshot I assume this is in reference to a table enhanced by Bootstrap DataTables.  That being the case, a more comprehensive solution might be to make use of the `columnDefs` option in your JS configuration:

https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.orderable

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "columnDefs": [
    { "orderable": false, "targets": 0 }
  ]
});
```